# How do I match more than one string separated by single dot

Tags: python, regex

I have the following conditions:

1. Has an "@" symbol;
2. Before the "@" symbol, there can be one or more
   strings made of letters, numbers, and underscores, separated by a
   single dot.
3. After the "@" symbol, there can be two or more strings made
   of letters, numbers, and underscores, separated by a single dot.
4. No other characters besides letters, numbers, underscores, dots, and the
   The "@" symbol should appear in the email address.

For example, your regular expression should match email addresses like:
`abc@umich.edu, 8ab.c_def9@example.regex.com`

But your regex should not match:
`abc@ def., ab..abc@def.com, abc@def`

How do I get more than one string that is separated by a single dot without typing `\.` multiple times (depending on the number of strings)?

Answer (score 0):

I can not understate the quality of the [Python regex Howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html). Reading it will help you become a better programmer.

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'$([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+^')
```

Notes

- `*` to mean zero or more
- `+` to mean one or more
- `^` and `$` are start and end respectively to exclude any suffix
- The `.` must be backslash escaped

Comment: thanks! the $ and ^ should be swapped, but otherwise it works perfectly fine.